# Why isnt there syntax highlighting when i code

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Hey im using eclipse and i have the pydev plugin and am currently using python to write programs but for some reason there is no syntax highlighting. I just installed all this as of january 7th 2018. so everything is the new version but i have tried so many things from changing colors to installing themes but there is no syntax highlighting. all the text is just the same color which makes it a lot more difficult for me so any solutions?

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/EclipsePythonIntegration

Comment: My guess is that you have some issue in your installation, can you provide a screenshot to help diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
Go to Window → Preferences. Open PyDev and select Editors (actually click on 'Editors', don't just expand it). In the Appearance Color Options dropdown menu, select what you want to change.

[image: screenshot]

I took this tip from this link https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm